# $\|u\|\leq \|u+av\| \Longrightarrow \langle u,v\rangle=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Prove that $\langle u,v\rangle=0\Longleftrightarrow \|u\|\leq \|u+av\|$.

So far I can get the $\Longrightarrow$ very easily, but I need some help with the $\Longleftarrow$ implication, any hints would be greatly appreciated.  Please no answers, I just want a small nudge to get me in the right direction, I've been stumped on this for a little bit.  Here's what I have so far:

($\Longleftarrow$)

Assume $\|u\| \leq \|u+av\|$

$\|u+av\|^2=\langle u+av,u+av\rangle=\langle u,u\rangle+
\langle u,av\rangle+\langle av,u\rangle+\langle v,v\rangle=\|u\|^2+\bar{a}
\langle u,v\rangle+a\langle v,u\rangle+\|v\|^2=\|u\|^2+
\bar{a}\bar{\langle v,u\rangle}+a\langle v,u\rangle+\|v\|^2$

Thoughts/ideas?

Comment: Let $u = (1, 0)$ and $v = (1,0)$ and $a = 1$. Then $\|u\| = 1; \|u + av\| = 2$, but $\langle u, v \rangle = 1$. That seems to contradict your conjecture.

Comment: Do you possibly mean that the left side holds for *all* $a$?

Comment: yes, for all a in the field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that the inequality hold for all $a$, we have
$$
\|u\|^2\le\|u+av\|^2\tag{1}
$$
Let $a=t\langle u,v\rangle$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $(1)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\langle u,u\rangle
&\le\langle u+av,u+av\rangle\\
&=\langle u,u\rangle+2\mathrm{Re}\left(a\,\overline{\langle u,v\rangle}\right)+|a|^2\langle v,v\rangle\\
&=\langle u,u\rangle+2t\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|^2+t^2\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|^2\langle v,v\rangle\\
0&\le\left(2t+t^2\langle v,v\rangle\right)\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|^2
\end{align}
$$

Since the right hand side is $0$ when $t=0$, and the right side must always be greater than or equal to $0$, the derivative at $t=0$ must be $0$. That is,
$$
\langle u,v\rangle=0
$$

Comment: @user104254: sorry, it was just a hint, but enough time has passed that it seems fine to adjust the answer for a complex vector space.

Comment: @user104254: It seemed that the issues around $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ seemed to complicate the argument. I guess it's worth considering.

Comment: It's potentially worth noting here that from the first equality, one can just compute the real part of $a \overline{\langle u,v\rangle}$ in terms of the real and imaginary parts of $a$ and $\langle u,v \rangle$. Then taking appropriate limits along the real and imaginary axes shows that the real and imaginary parts of $\langle u,v \rangle$ must both be $0$. This approach might be more intuitive for some than setting $a = t \langle u,v \rangle$ and using derivatives.