# If $\|u\| \leq \|u+av\|$ for all $a \in F$, How can I show that $\langle u,v\rangle=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If $\|u\| \leq \|u+av\|$ for all $a \in F$,

How can I show that $\langle u,v\rangle=0$?

I know a standard solution uses $\operatorname{Re}$ and $t =$ something but was wondering if there was perhaps an easier solution? Thanks!

Comment: The [standard solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682814/u-leq-uav-longrightarrow-langle-u-v-rangle-0), for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $a > 0$,
\begin{align*}
2a \langle u, v \rangle
&= \langle u , u  \rangle - \langle u - av, u - av \rangle
+ a^2\langle v, v \rangle \\
&= \left\|{u}\right\|^2 - \left\|{u - av}\right\|^2 + a^2 \left\|v\right\|^2 \\
&\le a^2 \left\|v\right\|^2 \\
-2a \langle u, v \rangle
&= \langle u , u  \rangle - \langle u + av, u + av \rangle
+ a^2\langle v, v \rangle \\
&= \left\|{u}\right\|^2 - \left\|{u + av}\right\|^2 + a^2 \left\|v\right\|^2 \\
&\le a^2 \left\|v\right\|^2 \\
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\left| \langle u, v \rangle \right|
=  \frac{\left|2a \langle u, v \rangle\right| }{\left|2a\right|}
\le \frac{a^2 \| v\|^2}{\left|2a\right|}
= \frac{|a| \|v\|^2}{2}
\end{align*}

Since $a$ can be arbitrarily small, we conclude $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$.

See also [robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/682826/68107).
I suspect this is as simple as it gets.