# Show that if $\|u\| \leq \|u+av\|$ for all $a \in F$, then $\langle u,v\rangle=0$, without using derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, normed-spaces, inner-products

Before stating the question, I'd like to address the fact that there are other solutions to this problem. [Robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682814/u-leq-uav-longrightarrow-langle-u-v-rangle-0) uses derivatives in their argument to show that the vectors are orthagonal, and [6005's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706144/if-u-leq-uav-for-all-a-in-f-how-can-i-show-that-langle-u-v-ran) appears to assume the inner product is real if I'm understanding it correctly.

I assume that $u$ and $v$ are vectors in an inner product space $V$ over the field $F$, a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

I know that assuming the inequality is true, I can show that for all $a\in F$, $0\leq\text{Re}(\bar{a}\langle u,v\rangle )+|a|^2\|v\|^2$. From here, I can proceed by contradiction and assume $\langle u,v\rangle\not= 0$.

Then, this means that either $\text{Re}(\langle u,v\rangle )\not=0$ or $\text{Im}(\langle u,v\rangle )\not=0$. If the real part of the inner product is not zero, then depending on whether it is positive or negative, I can pick a real $a$ so that $\text{Re}(\bar{a}\langle u,v\rangle )+|a|^2\|v\|^2<0$ and arrive at a contradiction. Thus, the real part must be $0$, but how could I show that the imaginary part of the inner product must be zero as well?

Or, am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have calculated, the inequality $\|u\|^2 \le \|u + av\|^2$ constrains the real part of $\mathrm{Re}\left(\overline{a}\langle u, v\rangle\right)$, because

$$
\|u\|^2 \le \|u + av\|^2 = \langle u+av,u+av\rangle = \|u\|^2 +2\,\mathrm{Re}\left(\overline{a}\langle u, v\rangle\right) +|a|^2\|v\|^2
$$

gives us

$$
0 \le 2\,\mathrm{Re}\left(\overline{a}\langle u, v\rangle\right) +|a|^2\|v\|^2\tag1.
$$

We can use the freedom in choosing $a$ to compute both the real and imaginary parts of $\langle u, v\rangle$. We accomplish this by choosing real $a$ in the first case and imaginary $a$ in the second.

Specifically, let $\frac{\langle u, v\rangle}{\|v\|} = x + iy$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider two cases $a=-\frac{x}{\|v\|}$ and $a=-\frac{iy}{\|v\|}$. Substituting into $(1)$, we get

$$
0 \le -2\,\mathrm{Re}(x(x+iy)) + x^2 = -2x^2 + x^2 = -x^2 \\
0 \le 2\,\mathrm{Re}(iy(x+iy)) + y^2 = -2y^2 + y^2 = -y^2 \\
$$

which means that $x^2=y^2=0$ and hence $\langle u, v\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, this means that either Re(⟨u,v⟩)≠0 or Im(⟨u,v⟩)≠0. If the real part of the inner product is not zero, then depending on whether it is positive or negative, I can pick a real $a$ so that $\text{Re}(\bar{a}\langle u,v\rangle )+|a|^2\|v\|^2<0$ and arrive at a contradiction.

You can't separate into these two cases since the value of $\text{Re}(\bar{a}\langle u,v\rangle )$ depends both on the real and imaginary parts of $\left<u,v\right>$. You should choose $a$ so that $\bar{a}\langle u,v\rangle$ is rotated onto the negative real  axis. Then choose the magnitude of $a$ to arrive at the contradiction.

So you should get something like  $-r|\left<u,v\right>| + r^2\|v\|^2 \geq 0$ where $r = |a|$. This will be false for small enough $r$.

Edit: Changed "positive real axis" to "negative real axis".